# Changing a date format using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert a date that is in the format of `YYYYMMDD` to `MM/DD/YYYY` as it is being read from a database and written to an Excel file. Using Perl I would do the following:

```
var=~s/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])/$5$6\/$7$8\/$1$2$3$4/;
```

Keeping in mind that this is all happening in a "for row in rows" loop structure that is reading in the database info.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the `re` module at all?

Answer (score 4):

instead of using a regular expression you can use pythons [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

or you could combine the two, however it is you want, but this would be a more clear way to modify date formatting. python is a language where clarity and easy reading are as important as efficiency. looking at the code below one can see that i am modifying a datestamp, whereas using a regular expression it is quite unclear sometimes.

read the datetime element and then write it as you want:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datestring = '20121212' # 2012 / 12 /12 
>>> datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'12/12/2012'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for simple string operations - certainly no less clear...

```
>>> s = '20121213'
>>> '/'.join( (s[4:6], s[6:], s[:4]) )
'12/13/2012'
```

as opposed to:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\2/\3/\1', s)
'12/13/2012'
```

If you're going to insist using an re like you've posted below though

> dateFormatted = row["TRADE_DATE"] dateFormatted =
>   re.sub(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)', r'\5\6/\7\8/\1\2\3\4',
>   dateFormatted) – user1901341 5 mins ago

Then you could (ab)use string formatting as such

```
>>> '{4}{5}/{6}{7}/{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(*s)
'12/13/2012'
```

Comment: dateFormatted = row["TRADE_DATE"]
 dateFormatted = re.sub(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)', r'\5\6/\7\8/\1\2\3\4', dateFormatted)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a regex -- Python doesn't encourage them in the same way Perl does -- but you can certainly use one:

```
import re 
re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\2/\3/\1', datestring)
```

Comment: Thank you for the VERY quick response. I ended up doing:

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get to it simply here, without regex:

```
>>> s = '20121225'
>>> conv = '/'.join((s[6:8], s[4:6], s[0:4]))
>>> conv
'25/12/2012'
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response and elegant solution.